# Python+Selenium=None results in href?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

so I don't have a lot of exp with selenium and all that, I've tried to use youtube + some forum posts to create a scraping code, as I am a photographer I work with other guys in that area and it would be awesome to get the list of all photographers, let me present code, so basically FOR NOW, I am interested to get names of photographers here ONLY (later I would need to learn about pagination in selenium, but first I have to pass this issue):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
bloom ="https://www.photographer.org/?geodir_search=1&stype=gd_place&sgd_placecategory%5B0%5D=8&s=+&snear&sgeo_lat&sgeo_lon"
driver.get(bloom)

eList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('geodir-entry-title')


hrefList = []
for a in eList:
    hrefList.append(a.get_attribute('href'))

for href in hrefList:
    print(href)
```

The result is None, none, none, none, etc...
it should be "Tsukimi Photography", "Cherry Logan Photography" etc...

Any tips where I might be stuck?

Thanks

Comment: Suggest adding a bit more detail here. In particular, would be very helpful if you could show the query results from the web search.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the html I can see that the element with class `geodir-entry-title` has no `href` attribute. So the output on None is expected.   The expected value of the href is like "https://www.photographer.org/photographers/tsukimi-photography/"

```
<h3 class="geodir-entry-title">
   <a href="https://www.photographer.org/photographers/tsukimi-photography/" title="Tsukimi Photography">
      Tsukimi Photography
   </a>
</h3>
```

This can be done like the following.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
bloom ="https://www.photographer.org/?geodir_search=1&stype=gd_place&sgd_placecategory%5B0%5D=8&s=+&snear&sgeo_lat&sgeo_lon"
driver.get(bloom)

eList = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='geodir-entry-title']//a")))


hrefList = []
for a in eList:
    hrefList.append(a.get_attribute('href'))

for href in hrefList:
    print(href)
```

Comment: hmmm I see, well this makes things a bit clearer. tho I dont know why i though that I could actually pull TEXT from Href https://prnt.sc/ulgbs6 like on this screenshot.
with your code, I'm getting URL that's in that class, but i tht code will go deeper and get Text ? No? :/ XPATH tomorrow all day xD

Comment: I actually figured it out, basically its not href its TITLE, so then i will get text, makes sense, Jortega you are THE KING!

Comment: @Jortega You can also use EC as `visibility_of_all_elements_located()`